# Where should I implement e-mail logic in N-tier application?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, email, layer, n-tier-architecture

I'm a student working on a project with an N-tier structure (a web server application with ASP.NET).

I currently have three layers:
 * Presentation
 * Business logic
 * Data access (communication with database)

I want to implement e-mail logic (in order to send e-mail to users) but I'm not sure in which layer it would be appropriate.

Any suggestions from you experienced developers out there? Thank you!

Comment: what does your business logic cover ? do you do all you processing inside it ?

Comment: Yes. I use it to process data between the data access and presentation layer.

Comment: what mailer are you planning to use ? There are some nuget packages that use Razor Views for the body of the email, which would save you some time if you wish to send html emails. in this case, write your mailer code inside the presentation layer. If you want to send basic mails, develop them inside the BL.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Business Logic layer should be used. You should try and keep your presentation layer as much logic free as possible.